# How to do some changes to the html control based on focus events using backbone

Tags: html, backbone.js, input, focus, marionette

I have a some html controls like input etc. I would like to update some status based on the focus made to the control

for example:

I would like to find a input id who gets the focus.

I tries some thing like the below but it keeps calling the method.

```
events :{
  'focus #input' : "updateCurrentCell"
},

updateCurrentCell: function(event) {
  alert('updateCurrentCell called');
  // Update the current cell.
}
```

what is the wrong here i am doing?

Comment: Your questions isn't clear to me. What do you mean by "it keeps calling the method"? According to the code you've displayed, the method will be called each time the input gets focus. It would also help if you could put up a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply, once the control gets focus, according to my code over there it has to alert only once but the alert box is not getting closed and keeps showing the alert box. this is what is meant by this statement "it keeps calling the method"

Answer (score 1):

In `updateCurrentCell`, try adding a `console.log` message to make sure it's getting called repeatedly, and that you're not having an issue with being unable to close the alert box.

But if the function keeps getting called, it's because the input field keeps regaining focus. This could happen if you have some code forcing the focus on "#input" that gets executed each time it loses focus.

But without a jsFiddle reproducing the problem, it will be difficult to diagnose...

Comment: Thanks David, It is really funny to know the issue and still don't know why? If i use alert it gives this problem, if i use console.log it is  fine and gets focus only once. :)

Comment: What might be happening is that the input loses focus when the alert is displayed, but then regains focus when the alert is closed (triggering `updateCurrentCell`again). This might be due to some autofocus code (or js library) you're using. Also, you might want to use different events than "focus", e.g. "change", "keypress", and/or "blur".

Comment: @Anto: The main lesson here is "don't use `alert` for debugging", way too easy to accidentally build an alert-bomb or alter the behavior of your application.